# Tableview having remove button and removing data from tableview

Tags: uitableview, ios4

I have one tableview this is created programmatically it's having list of dataitems
now i want to place a button in each tableview cell and that button os remove button

when i press the remove button the appropriate cell dataitem should removed from tableview

any one plz answer this problem...

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one solution to this,

On some action click set `[self.browseTableView setEditing:TRUE];` and then you can handle the event using

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

in your delegate file, generally it could be set to the file owner.

You can also set the selective editing through

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if(indexPath == 0)
          return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

Here the indexPath will give you the row number

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you sri for your answer

Answer (score 0):

are you populating data from database?
if yes then make one cell with remove button onclick call a function that takes id of that data and will remove that data from database so it will be removed from table view also.

Comment: Thanks   No No i'm not populating data from database i use only single Mutablearray and display it in tableview

Comment: use javascript on click of butoon hide that tr ,give id to tr